# can't register a soft phone to asterisk11

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, asterisk, sip

I have a VM (on oracle vbox) running Fedora17. I've installed asterisk 11 on it from sources. I've followed the wiki for installation (https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Creating+SIP+Accounts) to the letter.

The ip on the VM machine running fedora is 192.168.1.7

and I can ping it from the host machine (Ubuntu 12.04), which is at 192.168.1.2

I've tried registering with ekiga with the following settings:

user: demo-alice@192.168.1.7. Password: verysecretpassword registar: 192.168.1.7
but I'm getting an error "transport fail".

Also, while trying to register I'm logged in to the asterisk CLI with verbose level 3 and debug level 4 and nothing appears.

some more relevant data:

I've added the following code to the end of my sip.conf.sample file:

```
[demo-alice]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=verysecretpassword
context=users
deny=0.0.0.0/0
permit=192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0

[demo-bob]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=othersecretpassword
context=users
deny=0.0.0.0/0
permit=192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
```

After I changed the sip.conf.sample file, I've created a copy of it and named it sip.conf.
then I logged in to the asterisk CLI and typed `sip reload`.

Then I'm trying to register and ekiga client from my host machine at 192.168.1.2 but it doesn't work and nothing appears on the asterisk CLI while in verbose mode level 3.

BTW, If there is missing information about my question, please don't close it. comment about what you need to know and I'll edit it in to the question. tnx.

Comment: Try enabling SIP debugging (`sip set debug on` or `sip set debug ip 192.168.1.x`).

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can ping the vm from other systems on your network?

Comment: Also, try turning your firewall off on the VM.

Comment: it was indeed the firewall in the VM. used `service iptables stop` to turn off. Problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll repost my comments as an answer.

Have you confirmed that you can ping the vm from other systems on your network?

Try turning your firewall off on the VM